# Troubleshooting Ingress stuck in "Progressing" state in ArgoCD

Tags: openshift, kubernetes-ingress, argocd

I've got ArgoCD running on OpenShift, and one Ingress it's trying to sync has been stuck in "Progressing" for quite a while now. Is there anywhere I can check to determine whether any progress is still being made, or what it's stuck on? How can I troubleshoot when ArgoCD reports no errors?

Comment: You should look at the events on the Kubernetes object. They're available in ArgoCD I believe or directly with kubectl or the tool of your choice.

Comment: Very likely this is not related to ArgoCD but to your ingress controller or definition.

Comment: Also you might get more help on ServerFault for such questions.

Answer (score 3):

I've faced with the same issue.
Please check [this thread on github](https://github.com/argoproj/argo-cd/issues/4863).
Just as a previous commenter mentioned, progressing status is caused by ingress implementation. Argo, in its turn, really lacks visibility on this matter. There are more details explained in [this comment](https://github.com/argoproj/argo-cd/issues/4863#issuecomment-1400786602).

Answer (score 0):

Argo CD has listed some known issues regarding this: https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq/#why-is-my-application-stuck-in-progressing-state

In your case it might be that `status.loadBalancer.ingress` is empty.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the similar issue, but with a Deployment resource.

What I did was:

1. I looked in ArgoCD for the ghosted resource.
2. I copied the contents desired manifest tab.
3. I applied the contents manually through the add window in the openshift console.
4. I scaled down the resource so it would give a healthy state, and not prevent syncing.

Answer (score -2):

because status.loadBalancer.ingress data of ingress svc is empty. try use LoadBalancer svc type

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).